# compare String[] and crash app

Tags: android, string

I have a big problem... I want check if S1[1] is empty.
is populated dynamically but I want to know when it is full or when it is empty

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
public String[] S1 = new String[200];
....

btnArrivi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 try {

                     if(S1[1].equals(""))
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, S1[1]
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    .....
                     Fragment a = Check(S1); 

                 }

            }
     });
```

My application crashes. I have tried :

```
f(S1[1].isEmpty(""))
```

My logcat doesn't work on eclipse... :( 
If I delete:

```
if(S1[1].equals(""))
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, S1[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My application works...
can you help me please?

If S1 isn't empty, works.
Thank you!

EDIT:
logcat:

```
    05-09 07:35:48.655: E/chromium(3421): [ERROR:chrome_browser_main_android.cc(130)] Not implemented reached in void RecordBreakpadStatusUMA(MetricsService*)
05-09 07:35:49.460: E/Nova.Workspace(2867): The Hotseat screen must be >= 0 and < 1 (was 1); skipping child
05-09 07:35:49.465: E/Nova.Workspace(2867): The Hotseat screen must be >= 0 and < 1 (was 2); skipping child
05-09 07:35:50.630: E/RestStorages(2827): using folders=/storage/extSdCard/Musica/
05-09 07:35:51.150: E/FbInjectorInitializer(3510): Multi-binding Key[type=com.facebook.common.init.INeedInit, annotation=[none]] wasn't declared.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I have updated adt but now logcat doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse? Alternatively, you can run `adb logcat` from the command line (assuming your PATH is set correctly).

Comment: Yes i have tried to restart eclipse... PATH of ADT?? where check?

Comment: setting the PATH environment variable for your OS. The details depend on which OS you use. Do a google search for details.

Comment: adb is in sdk/platform-tools. I assume you mean isEmpty(), not isEmpty(""). What happens if you get rid of the Toast line, and just try to access a method of S1[1]?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to display an empty string??

Comment: @user234461 i want only check if S1[1] is empty. If i try isEmpty() crash...
@ Code-Guru i have edited 1st post... logcat don't rappreset my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
if (S1[1].equals("")) {
   ...
}
```

Do this:

```
final String s = S1[1]; // Can be null
if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
   ...
}
```